# How call class html from <Div>?

Tags: html

I have this code

```
<p class=‘majed’ style="color:#FF0000";>Red paragraph text</p>
```

If I want to call this class above

```
<Div class=‘majed’ > </Div>
```

Thank you, I am sorry because I am weak for English

Comment: What do you mean by 'call the class'? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Side note, fix the curly quotes you're using. `class=‘majed’`

Comment: Since you say you're weak in English... The word is "Please", not "Plz", and "you", not "u" :). However, more important than misspellings is helping us to understand what it is you're trying to do; please read [ask] for help with that process.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `;` in `<p class=‘majed’ style="color:#FF0000";>Red paragraph text</p>` while you should replace the `<Div>` with a `<div>`. If you intend to call the class **'majed'** then you should already have defined it in a stylesheet. Something like

```
<styles>
  .majed{
   //Add your styles here  
  }
</styles>
```

Then call it in

```
<div class="majed" >Text </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you say you want the class `majed` to do anything, you should add some CSS:

```
<style>
    .majed {
        color: #FF0000;
    }
</style>
```

Then you can just have

```
<p class="majed">Red paragraph text</p>
```

and it will also be applied to

```
<div class="majed">Text</div>
```